# What is the role of undefined exception handler (__und_svc) in kprobes?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, armv7, systemtap, kprobe

I tried to convert the kprobe as loadable kernel module.

I am able to run the samples available in `samples/kprobes/` folder from
kernel tree.

If we configure kprobes in kernel(`CONFIG_KPROBES`), then `svc_entry` macro will be expanded with 64 bytes in `__und_svc()` handler.

**Reference :** 
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S?a=arm#L245

My aim is without touching kernel side, make kprobe as kernel module.

so kernel is compiled without enabling CONFIG_KPROBES. so svc_entry macro will be expanded with 0 in 
[__und_svc()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S?a=arm#L251)

I would like to get cleared from these doubts.

1. If kprobe is handled undefined instruction exception(bcos kprobe
   only created), then why `__und_svc()` is invoked. what is the role of `__und_svc()` handler with respect to kprobes??
2. If 64 bytes memory is compulsory, then how to allocate without
   compiling the kernel. i.e How to do it dynamically.??

Please share your knowledge.

Comment: Although I like precise questions at SO, I'm afraid this one is too specific. Have you tried one of the kernel related mailing lists as well?

Comment: Yes. I posted this question on systemtap mailing list as well as linux-arm mailing list. Bad luck is in linux-arm it is not yet published.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may not get responses as your understanding of things is not very good and it will take some time for anyone on the *linux-arm-kernel* list to respond.  Read [kprobes.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kprobes.txt) and study the ARM architecture in detail.

> If kprobe is handled undefined instruction exception(bcos kprobe only created), then why `__und_svc()` is invoked. what is the role of `__und_svc()` handler with respect to kprobes?

On the ARM, mode `0b11011` is the *undefined instruction mode*.  The flow when an *undefined instruction* happens is,

1. lr_und = pc of undef instruction + 4
2. SPSR_und = CPSR of mode where the instruction occurred.
3. Change mode to ARM with interrupt disabled.
4. PC = vector base + 4

The main vector table of step four is located at [`__vectors_start`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S#n1130) and this just branches to 
[`vector_und`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S#n1080).  The code is a macro called [`vector_stub`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S#n949), which makes a descision to call either `__und_svc` or `__und_usr`.  The stack is the 4/8k page that is reserved per process.  It is the kernel page which contains both the task structure and the kernel stack.

**kprobe** works by placing *undefined instructions* at code addresses that you wish to probe.  Ie, it involves the *undefined instruction handler*.  This should be pretty obvious.  It calls two routines, [`call_fpe`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S#n495) or [`do_undefinstr()`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/traps.c#n397).  You are interested in the 2nd case, which gets the opcode and calls `call_undef_hook()`.  Add a hook with [register_undef_hook()](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/traps.c#n363); which you can see [`arch_init_kprobes()`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/kprobes.c#n608).  The main callback [`kprobe_handler`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/kprobes.c#n203) is called with a `struct pt_regs *regs`, which happens to be the extra memory reserved in `__und_svc`.  Notice for instance, [`kretprobe_trampoline()`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/kprobes.c#n370), which is playing tricks with the stack that it is currently executing with.

> If 64 bytes memory is compulsory, then how to allocate without compiling the kernel. i.e How to do it dynamically.?

No it is not.  You can use a different mechanism, but you may have to modify the *kprobes* code.  Most likely you will have to limit functionality.  It is also possible to completely re-write the stack frame and reserve the extra 64bytes after the fact.  It is **not an allocation** as in `kmalloc()`.  It is just adding/subtracting a number from the supervisor stack pointer.  I would guess that the code re-writes the return address from the *undefined handler* to execute in the context (ISR, bottom half/thread IRQ, work_queue, kernel task) of the *kprobed* address.  But there are probably additional issues you haven't yet encountered.  If `arch_init_kprobes()` is never called, then you can just always do the reservation in `__und_svc`; it just eats 64 bytes of stack which will make it more likely that the kernel stack will overflow.  Ie, change,

```
__und_svc:
    @ Always reserve 64 bytes, even if kprobe is not active.
    svc_entry 64
```

`arch_init_kprobes()` is what actually installs the feature.

Comment: thanks for enlightening `call_undef_hook()` related stuff. More informative. But I can't change the __und_svc() from entry-armv.S. In commit `d30a0c8bf99f0e6a7d8c57bd4524039585ffbced` only this 64 byte is added. so I'm trying to understand, for which feature/bug they added.

Comment: Just patch your kernel.  Set *entry-armv.S*, `svc_entry` with the code that adjusts the task and then always use `svc_entry 64`.  You don't need to pull the full patch set.  `git diff d30a0c8bf99~1..d30a0c8bf99` gives me a complete patch.  You can save it and run `echo svc_entry.patch | patch -p1`.    Or are you asking if you can not recompile the kernel and fix this?  This is  next to impossible; you have to re-write all of the *arm/kernel/kprobes.c* code.

Comment: My requirement is without applying any patch or even single change to kernel, modify the kprobes as LKM. so I dont have options except rewriting arm/kernel/kprobes.c.